# How to add Tabs inside fragment - Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Complete code: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CbzT8rlxmnzxf64czEaflEl1MXdeuUd-?usp=sharing).

I created with the ready template "navigation drawer", like the image below:

[image]

Follow code:

**Fragment2.cs**

```
public class Fragment2 : Fragment
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public static Fragment2 NewInstance()
        {
            var frag2 = new Fragment2 { Arguments = new Bundle() };
            return frag2;
        }


        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment2, null);
        }
    }
```

**fragment2.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/fragment2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**main.axml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
  <!-- The main content view -->
  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout">
      <include
          android:id="@+id/toolbar"
          layout="@layout/toolbar"
          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </RelativeLayout>
  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      android:id="@+id/nav_view"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
      app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = null;
switch (position)
{
    case 0:
        fragment = Fragment1.NewInstance();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = Fragment2.NewInstance();
        break;
}
```

How to put 2 tabs inside the fragment? Same as the picture below:

[image]

I create a navigation drawer, each menu has its fragment, this fragment has 2 tabs. I need help like putting 2 tabs in xamarin C#.

Any solution how to put 2 tabs inside my fragment?

Comment: use viewpagers its very simple look at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CrJxmSwXV_w

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I'm going to watch the video.

Comment: Did it work or not?

Comment: Use [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) which provides a horizontal layout to display tabs and [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

[Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34484.xamarin-android-working-with-material-design-tablayout-and-viewpager.aspx) is a tutorial about how to use `TabLayout + ViewPager` in Activity, because the fragment is similar with Activity, so you can do the same thing in Fragment.

Comment: @G.hakim, I tried to do it and it did not work. I'll try the answer below.

Comment: I edited the question, there is the full code loaded in Google Drive. Please help me.

Comment: Hi, I had make a mistake, because you are using nested fragment, so we need pass the `ChildFragmentManager` to avoid the blank page when you display it again. I have changed my answer based on your project, please check.

Comment: It works, thank you, @JoeLv-MSFT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Fragment1`:

```
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Support.V4.View;
using Android.Views;
using Java.Lang;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace NavigationDrawerAndTabs.Fragments
{
    public class Fragment1 : Fragment
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public static Fragment1 NewInstance()
        {
            var frag1 = new Fragment1 { Arguments = new Bundle() };
            return frag1;
        }


        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View inflate = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment1, container, false);

            ViewPager viewPager = inflate.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewPager);
            MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(ChildFragmentManager);
            viewPager.Adapter = adapter;

            //TabLayout 
            TabLayout tabLayout = inflate.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.sliding_tabs);
            tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);

            return inflate;
        }

        public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
        {
            public string[] titles = new string[] { "Tab1", "Tab2" };
            List<Fragment> fgls = new List<Fragment>();
            public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fm)
                : base(fm)
            {
                fgls.Add(Fragment2.NewInstance());
                fgls.Add(Fragment3.NewInstance());
            }

            public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int position)
            {
                return fgls[position];
            }

            public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
            {

                return new Java.Lang.String(titles[position]);
            }

            public override int Count
            {
                get { return titles.Length; }
            }


        }
    }


}
```

`Fragment1's layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
      android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:tabMode="fixed">

  </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/viewPager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
  </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

`Fragment2`:

```
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Views;

namespace NavigationDrawerAndTabs.Fragments
{
    public class Fragment2 : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public static Fragment2 NewInstance()
        {
            var frag2 = new Fragment2 { Arguments = new Bundle() };
            return frag2;
        }


        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment2, container, false);
        }
    }
}
```

`Fragment3`:

```
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Views;

namespace NavigationDrawerAndTabs.Fragments
{
    public class Fragment3 : Fragment
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public static Fragment3 NewInstance()
        {
            var frag3 = new Fragment3 { Arguments = new Bundle() };
            return frag3;
        }


        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment3, container, false);
        }
    }
}
```